# Check if an argument is a certain array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, if-statement, parameter-passing

I have two arrays, which I want to pass as arguments to another Sub:

```
Public arr1 As Variant
Public arr2 As Variant

Sub Main()
    arr1 = listSheet.Range("E2:G4").Value
    arr2 = listSheet.Range("H2:J60").Value

    call mySub(arr1)
    call mySub(arr2)
End sub()
```

In the "other" sub, I need to check which array is passed, but none of the below options is working:

```
sub mySub(ByRef myArr As Variant)

    if myArr=arr1 Then
    'do actions
    end if
'and I also tried:
    if myArr is arr1 then
    'do actions
    end if
end sub
```

How can I possibly check this using an IF statement, or is this doable in any other way?

Comment: Why not send the array plus an identifier (e.g. "arr1")as a string when calling the subroutine?

Comment: @MiguelH yeas, that would do it; nice workaround! but is there a way to compare the arrays...?

Comment: It depends on the kind of comparisons you want to make. You could always pass both arrays to the sub at the same time and do the comparison?

Comment: From your example, checking the [LBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx) &
[UBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx) properties of each rank would show the dimensions (which are substantially different). Also, why not pass both arrs into the sub are preprocess them at hte same time?

Comment: @Jeeped: the MySub is supposed to apply some transformations on an array, and the only difference is a small extra-step, which only needs to be done on one of them - so I guess not passin both arrays is the best solution. The LBound UBound is also a good workaround, but it does feel a bit somehow... not quite the answer I am looking for, as it still involves an additional step

Comment: Pass the range objects, which you declare as public variables.  Also make the variants arrays public. Then use the `Is` keyword to test which object was passed and do your modifications.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: I am not sure I follow; I am sort of a beginner in VBA, though What do you mean by "make the variants arrays public" ? Something else than declaring them as Public, which I already did?

Comment: I'm referring to arr1 and arr2.  But you only need to do that if you want to refer to them in your `Sub Main` after you have processed them.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I see - in order to use them in different modules, I declared them as public (edited the initial question); But the "IF" statements still don't work

Comment: I'll post an example that hopefully you can adapt, as it is not clear to me what else you want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the variables as range objects, and use the `Is` test. e.g:

```
Option Explicit
Public q8bAnswerList As Variant
Public q9AnswerList As Variant
Public r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Sub Main()
    Set r1 = Sheet1.Range("E2:G4")
    Set r2 = Sheet1.Range("H2:J60")

    Call mySub(r2)
    Call mySub(r1)

End Sub

Sub mySub(ByRef MyR As Range)
    Dim MyArr As Variant
MyArr = MyR
If MyR Is r1 Then
  Debug.Print MyR.Address
  Stop
ElseIf MyR Is r2 Then
    Debug.Print MyR.Address
    Stop
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I get it now - I thought that r1 and r2 were already arrays, but they were in fact ranges. Clear now why it was not working. Thanks for helping a begginer :)